# Plone: Up and Down arrows in Contents page of folder missing. Cannot move items up or down

Tags: plone, zope

We are using Plone 4.1.3.   When we go to the Contents page of a folder, there appears to be Up and Down arrows in the first column of the table in the page for a split second.   I suppose these Up and Down arrow are for changing the display order of the items and subfolders inside the folder.  Since these arrows are now gone, there is no way we can change the display order of an item in a folder.    Instead Up and Down arrows, there is just a icon showing 2 columns x 4 rows of tiny dots which does not respond to mouse click.  Is this a bug?

Thank you very much in anticipation.

cmgui

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rather than clicking quickly, click-and-drag those 2x4 tiny dots up and down. You can drag items anywhere in the table.

With JavaScript turned off you'll see Up and Down arrows. Clicking one will move the item one place up/down. The split second change you see is your browser loading the JavaScript that replaces the up/down arrows with the draggable dots.