# Plone: How to hide some tabs at the top of Plone portal

Tags: plone, zope

We are using Plone 4.1.3 and because of a bug in the Contents page of a folder, and we want to make a folder not to appear as a tab at the top of the Plone portal.  Also, we want to do this without disabling Automatically generate tabs in Site Setup's Navigation settings.   We found this documentation here: http://plone.org/documentation/kb/changing-tabs, and tried to follow the instructions but in our ZMI's portal_actions tool page, we do not see the items (that are supposedly the tabs?) as mentioned in the documentation.  Instead we see these under Name Type in portal_actions:document_actions, site_actions, folder_buttons, object, object_buttons, portal_tabs, user.  And in portal_tabs, there is only one name type: index_html (Home)  where Home is our root folder.

Can somebody advise us on how to manage the tabs at the top of the Plone page - i.e. how to hide some tabs (i.e. make some items not appear as tabs)?

Thank you very much in anticipation.

cmgui

Comment: I solved the ordering using Firefox 10.0.2 on a Mac...

Comment: Thanks Yuri.   Actually the ordering works.  Instead of clicking on the icon, drag it to move the items up or down.   Somebody answered the post.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526294/plone-up-and-down-arrows-in-contents-page-of-folder-missing-cannot-move-items

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.   In the Edit page of the folder, click on the item and then click on Edit of the item.  In the Edit page of the item, click Settings and select Exclude from navigation.